# How to draw an image on another image?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have a UWP `SoftwareBitmap` to which I would like to add padding on two sides (as if it's shown in **Fit** mode) and get the result as a `SoftwareBitmap`. I assume I need to copy it onto a new empty `SoftwareBitmap`, but I can't find any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> How to draw an image on another image?

You could use [Win2D](https://github.com/microsoft/Win2D) library to draw an image with padding. If you used `SoftwareBitmap` as the source, please try to convert it to file at first and you could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging#save-a-softwarebitmap-to-a-file-with-bitmapencoder).

We need to make **Win2D** `CanvasRenderTarget` and set it's width as `image width + 2 * padding width`. Then use `CanvasRenderTarget` to create `DrawingSession` and draw your image. For more please refer to the following code.

```
// file parameter is the image file
using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{   //padding width
    float padding = 30;
    var device = new CanvasDevice();
    var bitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(device, stream);
    var renderer = new CanvasRenderTarget(device,
                                          bitmap.SizeInPixels.Width+ 2*padding,
                                          bitmap.SizeInPixels.Height, bitmap.Dpi);
    using (var ds = renderer.CreateDrawingSession())
    {   // draw image from point xy = point(padding,0)   
        ds.DrawImage(bitmap,padding,0);
    }
    stream.Seek(0);
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await renderer.SaveAsync(randomAccessStream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Png);
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(randomAccessStream);
    var softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();

}
```

> I need to copy it onto a new empty SoftwareBitmap, but I can't find any way to do that.

You could use [`CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.softwarebitmap.copy) method to copy the current SoftwareBitmap into the provided SoftwareBitmap object.